# How to get LDAP displayname and email id using Msbuild?

Tags: powershell, msbuild, powershell-2.0, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

I got communitytasks to send mail. But in subject itself if i add display name of LDAP user, I would know who is taking build.

Following Code in Powershell would give me mail id and displayname

```
    $searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$env:USERNAME)"
    $mailid= $searcher.FindOne().Properties.mail
    $DispName= $searcher.FindOne().Properties.displayname
```

Is there any way to get mail id and displayname in Msbuild or is it better to call powershell commands through inline task?

Answer (score 1):

In [MSBuild you can refer to environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) as if they were defined properties, so taking the name of the user is as simple as writing `$(USERNAME)`.

Comment: When Username is in LDAP, normally Employee id will be username. That's why i am trying to get displayname from LDAP. My username in system will be some number. My display name will show my name